# Is it possible to build a collapsible fuel tank for in-orbit assembly?

Tags: orbital-assembly

In orbit propellant depots could be valuable in the near future. Assume they would be used for storing fuel harvested in situ from the moon and NEOs (So primarily H2, O2 and maybe CH4). Assume in orbit assembly techniques on par with what was available for the ISS. Is there any way to design fuel tanks such that they are modular/collapsible to allow the tanks to be transported to orbit and assembled there? The goal is to have tanks with much higher total capacity then could be held within assembled tanks on the same launcher.

Comment: What are your assumptions? For example, if you assume EVA assembly is possible, a bunch of aluminum sheets could be sent up and welded together at the ISS into tankage.  You need to narrow your question down some, add what you are assuming is available.

Comment: You need to specify what fuel you intend to store as well, whether it is cryogenic or not, and what other properties it may have. Hydrazine is corrosive and cryogenic fuels need to be insulated, which would need to be factored in.

Comment: Inflatable tanks would be quite simple to deploy, just pump gas inside them. Not sure if they could hold enough pressure, or do cryogenic or whatever complications you'll face.

Comment: Would probably be easier to just bring full tanks than to assemble them on orbit: we already do this all the time. Instead of discarding spent second stages, bring them all the way to orbit and then repurpose those.

Answer (score 1):

Answer: **Tidally locked toothpaste tubes**

Large volume pressure vessels (larger than the delivery vehicle) have to deal with a number of issues:

Any space-based propellant tank will be a pressure vessel, even if it only deals with the vapor pressure of hydrocarbon fuel.

Wall tension depends on shape and curvature. For a thin wall cylinder, tension is proportional to radius, but volume increases with the square of radius. Big is good.

For spheres, wall tension is proportional to radius but volume increases with the *cube* of radius. For a given volume, a spherical tank will mass less than a cylindrical tank. Big is even better.

However, spheres are complex curves. Unlike cylinders, they cannot be assembled from components with simple curves. This makes assembly in space challenging. You can't make complex curves from rolls of material. And you can't collapse complex curves into simple curves, either.

Any tank needs fixtures for manifolds, sensors, pumps, etc. which can be challenging to install on thin-walled containers.

Propellant/ullage separation complicates the design. Diaphragms have significant mass since they must be half the surface area of the tank. Capillary sponges use surface area which scales poorly with large tanks. Centrifugal separation has its own problems.

**One solution** is cylindrical tanks, tidally locked, manufactured by automated on-site spiral welding.

[image]

*Surface Production Operations Facility Piping and Pipeline
SystemsVolume III MAURICE STEWART*

The pipe would then be finished into a “toothpaste tube” hundreds of meters long.

[image]

Don’t show this to Elon or he will retool to build Starships this way.

[image]

The “cap end" would contain all manifolds, etc. Tidal forces would orient the tank radially in orbit. Propellant would gather at both ends (due to tidal acceleration) with ullage space in the center. An external raceway would connect the distal end to the manifold end.

If the tank must be insulated, a double tube-within-a-tube could be continuously formed with foamed insulation in between. See [Blowing UV-cured foam in space](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/64076/blowing-uv-cured-foam-in-space) .